# Can I rebuild a cordless drill batt-pack with regular AA Ni-mh batteries?

Tags: power, batteries

I have an 18v "Task Force" cordless drill that I got in Homedepot for $20 about 5 years ago and it has served me well. (A lot better that what I would have expected for the price paid)

It is still kicking bat the battery pack has finally died on me.

I am not an engineer but I've done a few things in the soldering and repairing of electronics and I feel confident that I can tackle this one.

My problem is that I am in a budget and the original SC1.2V 1000mAh Ni-Cd run for at least $2.50 each and i need 15 of them so at the end I am spending more on the pack than on the drill itself.

My question is what happens if I buy 15 AA regular Ni-Mh rechargable batteries and adapt them to the plastic casing? I know is not gonna look nice with all the duct tape I would have to use but is there any technical no-no or risk about switching from SC Ni-CD to AA Ni-MH?

The original charger which I was hoping to use delivers 24v and 400mA

At at least $37.50 for the real deal I don't mind risking the drill...

Thanks!

Comment: Look into [this thread](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33246/7036).  Not that it's a duplicate.

Comment: If you replace Ni-Cd with Ni-Mh you won't be able to use the original charger.

Answer (score 2):

I always do that, but I use cells of same capacity of the original cells, and the new cells must be specifically built to be welded toghether.

A cordless drill needs much current to works, so batteries MUST be welded and not simply connected with contacts and springs.

Also, NiMH cells will have shorter life than NiCd.

Comment: Welding is not always necessary.  I've gotten usable results (>20A peak) stacking retail NiMH D Cells (the 10Ah kind, not the ripoff AA-in-a-shell 2Ah kind) in a PVC sleeve and using heavy copper wires at the ends.  I'd agree that the typical spring and contacts plastic cases found in AM/FM receivers and other small electronics are useless for high current applications because the connecting wires are too small to handle the current and will overheat.  With cells stacked in a PVC shell, I have not noticed any heating problems.  Cells in a PVC shell can be removed for individual charge/exchange

Answer (score 0):

My answer to [the prior stack exchange question that Nick mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33246/how-to-rebuild-ni-cad-battery-pack-for-power-tools) still applies but you'd want 3 x 6V SLA in series and charging would be less standard.

You can use 12 x NimH in place of the older NiCd. There are "some issues".

For reasons explained below I suggest the following:

- Use 12 x 1500 mAh or lower capacity AA NimH.
- Charge by whatever means until fully charged.
- Trickle charge after main charge at say 50 mA for 24 hours or when not in use.
  DO NOT do this with 2000+ mAh cells!.
- Do not ever discharge pack under 12V loaded or say 13V unloaded.

I'd recommend an AA  cell of about 1500 mAh or less from a reputable manufacturer. This is because lower capacity cells have a greater ability to be trickle charged. Modern 2500 mAh cells do nort allow trickle charging at all.

When running many cells in series you run a very major risk of reverse charging one or more cells during **discharge**. What happens is that a cell in a string becomes exhausted but the current from the remaining partially discharged cells continue to flow and drives the exhausted cell into reverse polarity.  Long before this happens the discharge should have been stopped , but the condition can be hard to detect. If all the cells are perfectly balanced the effect does not occur as all discharge equally - it occurs when one or more cells are of lower capacity than the others.

Consider 12 cells with a nominal end point voltage of 1V each.
 12 x 1V = 12V.
 BUT 11 x 1.09V = 12V also.
 So a pack of 11 cells at 1.1V and 1 cell at 0V will look the same as a pack of balanced cells at 1V each.
 If the pack with a low voltage cell is discharged the cell will be damaged. It's lifetime will be shortened or in some cases it may be destroyed.  Taking a NimH cell under 1V is unwise so even a very small amount of imbalance in 12 cells can drive the lowest one too low.
 11 x 1.05 + 1 x 0.45 = 12V  :-(
 10 x 1.1 + 2 * 0.5 = 12V :-(
 9 x 1.17V + 3 x 0.5V = 12V :-(

---

Cell capacity is usually given the symbol C. C = 1 hour nominal discharge rate so C is the same as the Ah capacity at the one hour rate. . For a 2000 mAh cell C = 2A. C/10 = 0.2A etc.

Nimh are typically charged at about C although some specialist systems charge fatsr than this and some slow charge systems may charge at around say C10 or C20.

Cell imbalance is addressed by occasional "balancing - depending on battery chemistry this can be done in a range of ways. In the case of NimH simply applying a  charge current far lower than C for far longer than is needed for a full charge will allow lower capacity cells to "top up". For this to work the cells MUST be able to tolerate trickle charging at the rate used.

Reputable manufacturers say that modern NimH cells of around 2500 mAh capacity MUST NOT be trickle charged at all or, in a few cases, may be trickle charged for a short while or indefinitely at a very low rate indeed.

As a guide if you use 1500 mAh cells and charge the combined pack at C or less until nominally fully charged and then charge at no more than say C/20 for 10 or 20 hours a well balanced pack should be achieved.

---

Cell voltage is 1.2V nominal over much of range. Maybe 1.1V under heavy load.
 Cell is discharged at 1.0V loaded. Some small amount of energy is left BUT using it will lower the cell's lifetime.
 Cell will be at approaching  1.1V when discharged after standing O/C for some while.

Comment: How can you ensure 1.0 V in a cell? NiMH quickly discharges by itself even when not in use, isn't it? Most of my NiMH cells are near 0.0 V because I don't use these battery-powered devices often. (The same for NiCd.)

Comment: My suggested 50 mA trickle when not in use will solve the self discharge issue. This can be permanently applied if cells <= 1500 mAh are used. Modern LSD cells are hardly dearer and have very low self discharge rates. No NimH cell should be allowed to stand at much under 1V. Cycle them through a charger.